# Eloquent Javascript DOM <pre> manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working through [this](http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html#p_wZUvKB4q4J) example. I have implemented it as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
<pre>
Text in a pre element
is displayed in a fixed-width
font, and it preserves
both      spaces and
line breaks
</pre>

<p> This is here for contrast</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>

    <script>

anode = document.body.getElementsByTagName('pre');
re = /and/g;

/*
@param node is a (<pre> in this case) html node
@param keyword is a RegExp
 “syntax highlighter” that looks for <pre> tags with a data-language attribute and 
 crudely tries to highlight the keywords for that language  
*/
function highlightCode(node, keywords) {
  var text = node.textContent;
  node.textContent = ""; // Clear the node

  var match, pos = 0;
  while (match = keywords.exec(text)) {
    var before = text.slice(pos, match.index);
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));
    var strong = document.createElement("strong");
    strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
    node.appendChild(strong);
    pos = keywords.lastIndex;
  }
  var after = text.slice(pos);
  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(after));
}

highlightCode(anode, re)
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

When I run this file, I see no manipulation taking place. Using my web inspector I noticed that `anode = document.body.getElementsByTagName('pre');` may not be returning the `<pre>` tags because node.textContent seems to be returning undefined. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body.getElementsByTagName('pre');` returns an array of all the `pre` tags in the document. Change it to `document.body.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];` to have it return only the first `pre` tag.

Or enclose the entire contents of `highlightCode` in a for loop to have it highlight all `pre` tags in the document:

```
function highlightCode(node, keywords) {
  for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    var pre = node[i];
    var text = pre.textContent;
    pre.textContent = ""; // Clear the node
    var match, pos = 0;
    while (match = keywords.exec(text)) {
      var before = text.slice(pos, match.index);
      pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));
      var strong = document.createElement("strong");
      strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
      pre.appendChild(strong);
      pos = keywords.lastIndex;
    }
    var after = text.slice(pos);
    pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(after));
  }
}
```